# Google cloud sql active connection always on

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-sql, google-app-engine

I have a problem with my google app engin and cloud sql over billing due(I think) to the fact that for some reason I always have an active connection(seen in the cloud sql dashboard- active connections).

so I created a new instance in the project which i didnt authorize to any apps or requested an IP for neither did I setup up the instance with my DB, nothing is supposed to be there and still there is **always an active connection**.

I really dont understand this. why is there always an active connection even when there is nothing there and nothing connected to it.
I also waited for way over 15 minutes to see if the connection would turn off but no.

I dont know what to do and as I have the bronze account I cant even ask for support with google.

Please help,
Ido

Comment: even with a bronze account you have billing support, so if it really is a discrepancy, they can look into it, I believe.

Comment: Also please include (censored) output of 'gcloud sql instances describe your_instance', especially the activationPolicy and pricingPlan.

Comment: Oops, missed the first sentence: Please run "SHOW PROCESSLIST;" on your MySQL instance to see what other connections are open.

Comment: @David, right now I have 3 active connections according to the cloud sql dashoboard but on the show processlist, I see only 2. one is the show query and the other one is in the sleep command

Comment: @Patrice, I tried turning to the billing support so they could maybe clear some part of this at, least, but they still havent answered. last time I asked them something it took them over a month to reply so i`m not keeping up my hopes there

Comment: Per https://cloud.google.com/sql/pricing , you're not billed "per active connection".  To quote, "If you create a per use instance but do not use it, you are still charged for the storage cost".  The examples at https://cloud.google.com/sql/pricing#pricing-examples start exactly with a D0 instance with no use, which comes to $0.27 per month, followed by one used 10 hours per week with tiny queries, which comes to $1.24 per month.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @AlexMartelli. but I really don`t understand this. I have a project with  an instance which is barely used(not more then a few hours a week) but I receive a bill for over 400 usage hours on average a month. Every request that is made to the server I open a connection to the db and close it afterwards but still when I look at the active connection dashboard I see that there are always 1 or 2 active connections. this is really troubling as I`m paying 50$ a month and thats before I went production. please help